# What are effective ways to merge different parts of a document to form a single document?

Tags: machine-learning, graph-neural-network

I have a dataset where I have 3 different columns (Title, Keyword and Abstract) representing a document. I have to build a text classification model using TextGCN, where documents and words will be presented as graph to a neural network.

A basic approach that I am using is to concat all 3 columns into 1 to represent a single document. Are there any better strategies that we can apply to represent a single document ?

Answer (score 0):

The original TextGCN paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05679.pdf mentions separate nodes for words and for documents, and the embeddings for both words and documents are simultaneously learned, so you could probably concatenate your titles, abstracts, and documents into a single node as you mention as a starting point, and refine from there. Refining could mean separate nodes for each word, or you could consider separate nodes each for words, titles, abstracts and documents, or some sort of hybrid approach. Note that if you have separate nodes for words, titles, abstracts, and documents, you will want to ensure that you allow message passing between the same types of nodes, even if they are not directly connected.